# Is buildToolsVersion of android depended on SDK version installed

Tags: android, gradle

I am generating a maven archetype for an android gradle project .  I have a question regarding the

buildToolsVersion   used in the gradle script. Does it has to be related with the SDK version?

I tried with the below configurations still my tests worked fine

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

AND

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
```

Since there is no option to use the latest build tool version in gradle ,wanted to know if there is any other way .

regards,
Felix T

Answer (score 0):

These options correspond to the build tools and API version you are building against.  They are tied to the SDK, but are not the SDK.  If you load your SDK Manager you will see the Build Tools has a separate item and version.  There are also multiple "platforms" available (the API levels), etc.  You cannot specify a syntax for `buildToolsVersion` which will allow "this version or newer".